# Wxpython. wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl. List of URLs

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

There is an object:

```
self.m_textCtrl_text = rt.RichTextCtrl(self.panel, -1, self.text, wx.DefaultPosition, (500, 100))
```

Periodical I insert in it hyperlinks:

```
urlStyle = rt.RichTextAttr()
urlStyle.SetTextColour(wx.Colour(attrs['fill']))
urlStyle.SetFontUnderlined(strToBool(attrs['underline']))

self.m_textCtrl_text.BeginStyle(urlStyle)
self.m_textCtrl_text.BeginURL(attrs['link'])
self.m_textCtrl_text.WriteText(attrs['text'])
self.m_textCtrl_text.EndURL()
self.m_textCtrl_text.EndStyle()
```

How to find all the hyperlinks in the text? Is it possible to implement this?